# NetSuite reference custom field value on multiple forms

Tags: forms, netsuite

We have a custom field on our Customer form "client_type" and would like to be able to reference the same field's values on the Customer's Contacts as well on the Contact form. The data is populated for all Customers currently, though when creating the custom field on the Contact form and selecting 
`SOURCE LIST -> Parent` & `SOURCE FROM -> client_type` the Contact records do not have any data populated. Tried waiting to see if this was a caching issue as we saw with another modification in NS we did recently and there was no solution.

Comment: IIRC this only works if you have Store Value unchecked to make it a dynamic field - can you confirm if you have this?

Comment: Yes, tried doing that as well.